# Drawing lines from one marker to all other markers and open infowindows of each marker for click

Tags: google-maps, c#-4.0, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-api-2

[Please click here for screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aI1zj.png) I have Google map which shows the relation between locations based on a condition. What I need is to draw lines from one marker to all other markers and open info windows of each marker for marker click. Can anybody suggest the way to perform the task?

Comment: hope this is ur looking for https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/overlay-symbol-arrow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 var Markerss = {};
        var linearray = [];
        function initialize() {
            var markers = [{ 'lat': '32.803', 'lon': '-96.7699', 'ExpertsCount': 2, 'Type': 'ofsite' }, { 'lat': '44.9542', 'lon': '-93.1139', 'ExpertsCount': 3, 'Type': 'onsite' }, { 'lat': '32.903', 'lon': '-150.0011', 'ExpertsCount': 5, 'Type': 'offsite' }, { 'lat': '61.85', 'lon': '-97.6501', 'ExpertsCount': 9, 'Type': 'onnsite' }];
            var mapProp = {
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(28.067768, 2.150065),
                zoom: 5,
                mapTypeId: 'terrain'
            };
            //var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            //    content: "Hello World!"
            //});
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"), mapProp);
            var icon = "";
            for (i = 0; i <= markers.length; i++) {
                var data = markers[i];
                var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(data.lat), parseFloat(data.lon));
                if (data.Type == "offsite") {

                    icon = 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/green-dot.png';

                }
                else if (data.Type == "onsite") {


                    icon = 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/blue-dot.png';
                }
                else {

                    icon = 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/red-dot.png';
                }


                var div = document.createElement('DIV');
                div.innerHTML = '<div class="mapicon" id="dvIcon" style="background-image: url(images/mapiconsmall.png);" onmouseover="javascript:$(this).next().show()" onmouseout="javascript:$(this).next().hide()" ><div class="maindiv"style="width:24px;margin-top:3px; text-align:center;margin-left:1px;"><span style="font-weight:bolder;font-size:11px;"> ' + data.ExpertsCount + '</span></div></div><div id="dvExpName" style="display:none;z-index:1;position:absolute;">' + data.expName + '</div>';
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: myLatlng,
                    map: map,
                    title: i,
                    content: div,
                    flat: true,
                    anchor: RichMarkerPosition.MIDDLE,
                    icon: icon
                });

                Markerss[i] = marker;
                //if (data.Type == "onsite") {
                //    Marker[i].setClickable = false;
                //}
                //else {
                //    Marker[i].setClickable = true;
                //}
                // Attaching a click event to the current marker
                if (markers[i].Type != "onsite") {
                    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function (event) {
                        if (linearray.length != 0)
                        {
                            for (i = 0; i < linearray.length; i++) {
                                linearray[i].setMap(null);
                            }

                        }

                        var lineSymbol = {
                            path: google.maps.SymbolPath.FORWARD_CLOSED_ARROW,
                            scale: 3,
                            strokeColor: 'red'
                        };
                        for (j = 0; j < markers.length; j++) {
                            var marker = markers[j];
                            var lat = parseFloat(markers[j].lat);
                            var lon = parseFloat(markers[j].lon);
                            if (lat != event.latLng.lat()) {

                                var line = new google.maps.Polyline({
                                    path: [{ lat: event.latLng.lat(), lng: event.latLng.lng() }, { lat: lat, lng: lon }],
                                    icons: [{
                                        icon: lineSymbol,
                                        offset: '100%'
                                    }],
                                    strokeColor: 'red',
                                    map: map
                                });
                                linearray.push(line);
                            }

                            var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                                content: '<b><i>Expert Count:</i></b> <span>' + parseInt(markers[j].ExpertsCount) + '</span><br/><b><i>Expert Count:</i></b> <span>' + parseInt(markers[j].ExpertsCount) + '</span><br/>'
                            });
                            infoWindow.open(map, Markerss[j]);
                        }
                    });
                }
            }




        }
```

Comment: Does anyone have jsfiddle for this?